# Moving list items to create nested lists with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

Our CMS outputs some list items in the following format:

```
<ul class="tocList">
  <li><a href="#s6855">a list item</a></li>

  <li class="indent"><a href="#s4671">a list item</a></li>

  <li class="indent"><a href="#s6824">a list item</a></li>

  <li><a href="#s6856">a list item</a></li>

  <li class="indent"><a href="#s4672">a list item</a></li>

  <li class="indent"><a href="#s4673">a list item</a></li>

  <li class="indent"><a href="#s4674">a list item</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to change the structure to include correctly structured nested lists:

```
<ul class="tocList">
  <li><a href="#s6855">a list item</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="indent"><a href="#s4671">a list item</a></li>

      <li class="indent"><a href="#s6824">a list item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#s6856">a list item</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="indent"><a href="#s4672">a list item</a></li>

      <li class="indent"><a href="#s4673">a list item</a></li>

      <li class="indent"><a href="#s4674">a list item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To change the CMS logic would be too painful and cause our editors too much work. I'd like to achieve this with JQuery. I've been trying out various JQuery `.wrap()`, `.each()` functions with no joy.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jqVVK/

Comment: brilliant, thanks for the quick responses. Yusaf, you're solution almost worked, although it didn't nest the 'indented <li>s. Barmar's answer completed the function and did the trick nicely. I really must get on it an learn more JQuery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".tocList li:not(.indent)").each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil("li:not(.indent)").wrapAll("<ul/>");
    $(this).next("ul").detach().appendTo($(this));
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/RswN6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.tocList > li > a').each(function(i,v){
    var li = $(v).parent();
    li.nextUntil('li:not(.indent)').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
    li.next('ul').detach().appendTo(li)
});
```

Should do it.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v6DUh/)